# Remote path completion with scp on OSX

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, osx-yosemite, scp

On Linux, you can do

```
$ scp some-file.txt user@remote.host.com:/some/pa<tab>
```

and it would autocomplete the remote path, if you have key based authentication up and running for that host. However, on OSX it doesn't seem to work, using iTerm2. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your shell. In case you are using bash you need the correct bash completion scripts.

See the [Bash completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) project, and especially this script: https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/completions/ssh

Default location where those have to be put is `/etc/bash_completion` and then you can load them from your `.bashrc`or `.profile` file by adding something like `. /etc/bash_completion` (mind the . to source the file)

While focused on Linux they should work on Mac, too.

Homebrew and other software managers provide bash-completion, too. If installed check your `.bashrc`/`.profile` according to the instructions to properly load it.

Comment: Perfect! http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/bash-completion/bash-completion.git/plain/README helped me find the solution. I added  `if [ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion ]; then
   . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion
fi`to my .bash_profile and it works like a charm.

Comment: @johannes - Looks like your links here are dead

Comment: @HaemEternal I've now edited this and changed links to the GitHub project

Answer (score 0):

For `zsh`, as of approximately 2019 the default macOS shell, the brew package `zsh-completions` contains the functionality required to enable remote scp path completions (similar to functionality available, for example, in the default Ubuntu bash install).

If you don't have homebrew installed already, follow [these](https://brew.sh/) instructions.

To install the completions:

```
brew install zsh-completions
```

To enable the autocompletions, follow the instructions on the brew output. Typically this will involve adding to the `~/.zshrc` (but the output of brew is likely to be the most accurate/current):

```
echo 'if type brew &>/dev/null; then
    FPATH=$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh-completions:$FPATH
    autoload -Uz compinit
    compinit
fi' >> ~/.zshrc
```

You'll then need to adjust some permissions:

```
chmod go-w '/opt/homebrew/share'
chmod -R go-w '/opt/homebrew/share/zsh'
```

Now autocomplete for remote scp should work.

These instructions have been tested on macOS Ventura on Apple silicon (M1).